# Find free resolution of module

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and let $M=\mathbb{Q}$ be an $R$-module where $x \cdot a = 0 = y \cdot a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Is the following a free resolution of $M$?

Define $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]^{(1)}= \{ f: \{1 \} \to \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \}$ which is a free $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$-module with basis $f_1: \{ 1 \} \to \{ 1 \}$. Then $$0 \to (f_x,f_y) \overset{b} \to \mathbb{Q}[x,y]^{(1)} \overset{a} \to \mathbb{Q} \to 0$$ where $a$ is given by $f \mapsto f(1) \cdot 1$ and $b$ is the natural inclusion. ($f_x$ is the map $f_x: \{ 1 \} \to \{ x \}$.)

Is this a free resolution of $M$? Also, does the length of the resolution matter?

Comment: I don't think $(f_x, f_y)$ is a free $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ module...

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a resolution of $k[x,y]/(x,y) \simeq k$.

Note that we have an exact sequence (as you write yourself)
$$
0 \to (x,y) \to k[x,y] \to k \to 0.
$$
But as Najib Idrissi says in his comment, $(x,y)$ is **not** a free $k[x,y]$-module. For example, we have the relation $y \cdot x - x \cdot y = 0$.

What **is** true however, is that this is essentially the **only** relation. Thus the full resolution takes the form

$$
0 \to k[x,y] \xrightarrow{(-y,x)} k[x,y] \oplus k[x,y] \xrightarrow{(x,y)} k[x,y] \to k \to 0.
$$

This is a special case of the **Koszul complex**, which in general resolves complete intersections. For proofs of these claims, see any book mentioning the Koszul complex (for example Eisenbud's giant yellow book).